# Insufficient parameters supplied to the command' in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am trying to do a SQL query that calculates the number of days between two dates from a database.
However an error occurs when I try to search for specific data from the database. Furthermore does anyone know how I could use the sql Query that counts how many days is between two dates in a calculation, which would use data from another table. I have a room type table which has a room price column, and a booking table where I have the arrival date and departure date how could I calculate the total price for the booking.

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'unknown error
> Insufficient parameters supplied to the command'

Here is what I have so far

```
   Function GetDuration(ID As Integer, fname As String)
    Dim dsql As String = "Select Cast ((
                        JulianDay(Replace(departuredate,'/','-')) 
                        - JulianDay(Replace(arrivaldate,'/','-'))
                        ) As Integer)
                        from booking INNER JOIN customers on customers.CustomerID = booking.BookingID
                        where booking.bookingid = @ID or customers.fname LIKE @Fname;"
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr)
        Dim mycmd As New SQLiteCommand(dsql, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", DbType.String).Value = $"%{fname}%"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", DbType.Int32).Value = ID
        Dim value As Object = mycmd.ExecuteScalar()
        txtdurationofstay = value
    End Using

End Function
    Private Sub IbtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ibtnBSearch.Click
    If txtBookingSearchID.Text <> "" Then
        Dim SearchID As Integer
        If Int32.TryParse(txtBookingSearchID.Text, SearchID) Then
            DgvBookings.DataSource = GetData("null", SearchID)
            GetDuration(txtBookingSearchID.Text, "null")

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in the Search box.")
        End If

    ElseIf txtBsearchFname.Text <> "" Then
        DgvBookings.DataSource = GetData(txtBsearchFname.Text, 0)
        GetDuration(0, txtBsearchFname.Text)
    End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `mycmd` here:

```
Dim mycmd As New SQLiteCommand(dsql, con)
```

but added the parameters to `cmd` and not to `mycmd`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", DbType.String).Value = $"%{fname}%"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", DbType.Int32).Value = ID
```

and then you execute:

```
mycmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

but there are no parameters in `mycmd`.

Comment: By any chance do you how I could do what I asked in the second question?

Comment: @MiloszLaksa now I read it. This can be done probably with join(s) of the tables involved and a calculation (multiplication), but I can't say without sample data of all the tables and expected results.

Comment: should I post some of the sample data here or make an entirely new question?

Comment: @MiloszLaksa it's better to post a new question where you explain the requirement with sample data and expected results.